# Unity Mirror: Problem with using custom lists in combination with commands that call clientRpcs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mirror

important information:

- 1 client and 1 host
- both have a list of objects of a custom class (different lists)
- task is to add the one of the host in front of the one of the client and to have this version on the client and the host
- client calls command to start host recieves it and fills in his list and then calls a clientRpc and passes his list on to the client

The last step is the problem: The list that the host fills in in the command is correct (used Debug.Log() to observe) but the list recieved in the parameter on the client has the same length but the content is diffrent the objects are all blank (the variables of the objects have the value null even it wasn't like that on the hosts side).

I have no ideas how to solve the problem but to send the variable values seperated. The problem with this is that the data amount would be to great so that I am looking for a better alternative.

(Sorry for my bad english. If anyone of you speaks german, I can give you a better alternative of the problem in german.)
Thanks for your help!

my code:

```
using Mirror;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Übermittlung : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Judoka_speicher Js;

void Start()
    {
        if (isClientOnly) 
        {
            skipframe();
            Debug.Log("Sync-Start(c)");
            liste_synchronisieren_t1_command();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    private void liste_synchronisieren_t1_command() 
    {
        if (isServer && isClient) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Sync_Start(s)");
            List<Judokaklassenhalter.Judoka> judokas = Js.GetJudokas();
            Debug.Log(judokas[0].GetVorname());
            liste_synchronisieren_teil1(judokas);
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void liste_synchronisieren_teil1(List<Judokaklassenhalter.Judoka> alteListe) 
    {
        Debug.Log(Js.GetJudokas()[0].GetVorname());
        if (isClientOnly) 
        {
            List<Judokaklassenhalter.Judoka> liste = alteListe;
            Debug.Log("1.Sync-Befehl");
            Debug.Log(liste[0]);
            List<Judokaklassenhalter.Judoka> alteListe2 = Js.addListVorne(alteListe);
            liste_synchronisieren_t2_command(alteListe2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can simply synchronize lists this way ... could you show the implementation of `Judokaklassenhalter.Judoka`? An alternative might be to rather go through a string / byte[] instead

Comment: As a general suggestion (I'm German too ;) ): Code in **english**! It is **the** established programming language and makes communication of purposes of types and fields internationally easier ;)

Comment: @derHugo The code is to long but "Judoka" is a class in the script called "Judokaklassenhalter" it contains a few private variables (strings and integers), the constructors and the get/ set functions. Thanks for the idea of one string i think that will work but I expect like 300 object each with 6 strings of at least 5 characters. That will make it a really long string and the tranformation would take a too long time. But I will still consider your idea if there is no better solution to the problem.

Comment: I will consider your advice of writting my code in english or at least rewritting it before posting it, I actually never tought that it is relevant to understand variable and function names. But still tanks for your ideas.

Comment: I think (not sure) your classes basically need to be serializable (see [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules)) in order to be synchronizable ... so you might need to use fields, make your class `[Seriaizable]` and if your fields are private add `[SerializeField]` to them

Comment: sure now actually ;) See [Mirror - Allowed Data Types](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/manual/guides/data-types) describes exactly which members of your custom type will be synchronized, you didn't share it yet but I would claim your `Judokaklassenhalter.Judoka` doesn't fulfill those requirements

Comment: Well, it is a MonoBehaviour component ... according tot he doc you ca only sync `GameObject` and also only if it has a network identity aka it has been spawned network wide

Comment: My class:
'
[Serializable]
public class Judokaklassenhalter : MonoBehaviour 
{
    '[Serializable]
    public class Judoka
    {
        [SerializeField] private string vorname; //and a few more private strings
        [SerializeField] private int geburtsjahr;
        [SerializeField]
        public Judoka() 
        { }

        [SerializeField]
        public Judoka() //each variable has parameter in constructor
        {
            //setting variables to parameters of constructor
        }
        //get set methods are public
    }
}
'

Comment: As you see I added the [SerializeField] and [Serializable] it didn't help but I got it working by using public instead of private. And now the sync does work without it being a GameObject or having a NetworkIdentity. But anyhow thanks for your help. I will go with the public variables. I won't close the question for three days or so in order to see if anyone has a better solution then making the variables public. Thanks for your effort it really helped finding this "solution".

Comment: my question is still why is this a `MonoBehaviour` if it isn't supposed to be attached to a `GameObject`?

Comment: I changed it to ScriptableObject, is this correct?

Comment: depends .. are those scriptable object assets? if those are not supposed to be assets nor components at all just make it a normal class

Comment: I did it, but it still does not work with [SerializeField] and private but still thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to make the variables (strings and ints) in the class of the objects in the list public.